# How to make condition on context.get in Dialogflow fulfillment?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to make  if else condition on **token** if token is null or undefined or "" then it will redirect on event and if token comes from context.get than it will show **token exist**.
Please check my code but its not working its going to crash every time. Please help me out to get any solution.

```
function RaiseQuery(agent) {
    let token = "";
    const infoContext = agent.context.get('info');
    token = infoContext.parameters.token;
    if (token === null){
        agent.setFollowupEvent("Login");        
    } else {
        agent.add("Token Exist");
    }
}
```

Logs:
[image: Logs]
Thank You

Comment: When you say it crashes every time, can you update your question to indicate what error you're getting when it crashes? The more you can provide, the better our chances are of helping you.

Comment: @Prisoner This fulfillment function is not able to call. I checked the log `{
textPayload: "Function execution took 14 ms, finished with status: 'crash'" `

Comment: Updating your question to include the logs from execution would help. If you used the inline code editor, check the Logging section of the google cloud for the project associated with your Dialogflow project. If you're running this on your own resources, check the logs from there.

Comment: @Prisoner Please look at once in log.